# Undefined method 'should' when using Capybara with Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara, testunit

I am trying to use both Capybara and Cucumber in my Rails application. So, that's what i did:

- Installed gems needed and added them to the `Gemfile`
- Ran the `rails generate capybara:install --cucumber`
- Created a feature and its steps definitions for cucumber

Here's my feature (yeah, i am creating blog application):

```
Feature: Browse posts
    So that I can browse through the posts
    As a visitor
    I want to see all and/or particular posts

    Scenario: Viewing all the posts
        Given Posts exist
        When I navigate to the website home
        Then I should see all the posts

    Scenario: Viewing particular post
        Given Post #1 exists
        When I navigate to /posts/view/1
        Then I should see the post with id=1
```

And here's its step definitions:

```
Given /^Posts exist$/ do
    assert (not Post.all.empty?), "No posts found at all"
end

Given /^Post #(\d+) exists$) do |id|
    assert Post.find_by_id(id).valid?, "Post ##{ id } was not found at all"
end

When /^I navigate to (.+)$/ do |url|
    if url =~ /^the website home$/ then
        visit '/'
    else
        visit url
    end
end

Then /^I should see all(.+)posts$/ do |delimiter|
    posts = Post.all

    posts.each do |post|
        page.should have_content post.title
    end
end

Then /^I should see the post with id([^\d]{1,})(\d+)$/ do |delimiter, id|
    post = Post.find_by_id id

    page.should have_content post.title
end
```

And when running `rake cucumber` i get this message:

```
Then I should see all the posts     # features/step_definitions/browsing_posts.rb:13
  undefined method `should' for #<Capybara::Session> (NoMethodError)
  ./features/step_definitions/browsing_posts.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  ./features/step_definitions/browsing_posts.rb:16:in `each'
  ./features/step_definitions/browsing_posts.rb:16:in `/^I should see all(.+)posts$/'
  features/browsing_posts.feature:9:in `Then I should see all the posts'
```

What am I doing wrong? And yeah, are there any mistakes in my feature?

Comment: This won't solve your problem but improve the quality of your stories: `Given nothing` is not correct. `Given Posts exist` is more likely what you want.

Comment: are you using the default test::unit or with rspec? some of your syntax are more in the style of rspec

Comment: @prusswan actually, i am not sure =) i run tests with `rake cucumber` and i do not see any __rspec__ or __test::unit__ code provided by me. i suppose cucumber uses its own classes

Comment: In that case you *are* defaulting to test-unit and should use the expectation syntax that comes with it

Comment: @prusswan what's that _expectation syntax_??? I did not got the idea of your thoughts - are you talking about `assert`'s???

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Replace `page.should have_content post.title` with `assert page.has_content?(post.title)`. If that works, apply that similarly to the other `have_content` statements

Edit: Those [statements involving `should`](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#querying) are based on [rspec expectations](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-11/docs), and should be used only if you are already using rspec or some other testing framework that responds_to `should`. Coming from the test::unit angle, this is probably just another kind of `assert`.

Comment: Where do you find list of "asserts" that working for Minitest?

Comment: @JohanDonadoB. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#available-assertions would be a good starting point

Answer (score 4):

can you try

```
page.has_content?('foo')
```

instead of

page.should have_content post.title

if it works, then you can use this with assert.

Answer (score 2):

after facing the same issue I tried

```
expect(page).to have_content('foo')
```

which worked fine for me

Comment: This indicates that you were using a newer version of RSpec.